# What will be the best replacement of Interface If I want to Inherit two different classes in one children class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I want to apply some default configurations to my mvc web application.
here is my requirement

```
public class HomeController : Controller, Configs
{
  // action's and private methods goes here.
}
```

here Controller class is an abstract class and Configs class is an non-abstract(normal) class but c# compiler does not allow me to inherit multiple classes. I know that multiple inheritance is possible using interface in c#; but problem with interface is that, it must needed implementation of interface members.

Can any expert person help me?

Comment: You can implement multiple interfaces, but I wouldn't call that multiple inheritance. You don't really inherit anything from interfaces, interfaces force you to oblige to their contract. It's up to the implementing class to oblige to the interface.

Comment: What exactly is inside your `Configs`? I don't think it's a good idea to inherit from `Configs` because it doesn't really make sense. Your controller is not a more specific class and doesn't really have a relationship to configs.
Fe: `public class Dog: Animal` makes sense, because there's a clear relationship.
Alex answer with a basecontroller makes more sense. That way you can share all common controller code between your specific controllers.

Comment: @sniels thanks for your time and replay,
I know that, what you are suggesting, but this make **code repetition**.
if I have more then 10 controllers in my application. then I have to implement all members of interface to all controllers.

Comment: @sniels yes, right.

Comment: Yes, I agree, I'm not suggesting that ;) I was clarifying how interfaces isn't really inheritance, not really suggesting to you to use interfaces. I see how my comment is potentially confusing. Using a `BaseController` is really the way to go in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have an abstract base class that inherits another (`Controller`)

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
  //your base config stuff here
}
```

Then your `HomeController` can inherit `BaseController`
... which in turn inherits `Controller`

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{

}
```

While this will work, you can quickly get in a bit of a mess with multiple levels of inheritance.
A preferred aproach would be `Composition over inheritance`

One way of achieving this would be:

```
public class Configs
{
  //your base config stuff here
}   

public class HomeController : Controller //note only inherits framework controller
{

    private Configs _configs;

    public HomeController()
    {
        _configs = new Configs()
    }

    public ActionResult Home()
    {
        //use _configs here
    }
}
```

You could of course also inject `Configs` via IOC etc... but that's a bit out of scope for this answer.

Comment: this will work for me. an abstract class can inherit another abstract class. let me try. Thanks man.

Comment: first one is best then second one.

Comment: Sometimes it is, usually the 2nd way is better and cleaner.